# CaseArticle object SOQL query in Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, knowledge

I am trying to query CaseArticle object. In the following code I am not able to see any value getting populated in caseArt List. When i run the query in editor I am able to see the values. Can any one help figure out what mistake I am doing.

```
trigger ArticleStatusUpdate on Case (after update) {

    Set<Id> varCaseId = new Set<Id>();
    List<Case> caseUpdate = new List<Case>();
    for(Case caseId : Trigger.new)
    {

        varCaseId.add(caseId.Id );
    }
    System.debug('*** varCaseId **** '+varCaseId);
    List<CaseArticle> caseArt = [SELECT CaseId,KnowledgeArticleId FROM CaseArticle WHERE caseId = : varCaseId];

    System.debug('*** caseArt **** '+caseArt);
    for(CaseArticle ca: caseArt)
    {
        Case varCase = new Case();
        varCase.Id = ca.CaseId;
        varCase.Article_Created__c = true;
        caseUpdate.add(varCase);
    }
    System.debug('*** caseUpdate **** '+caseUpdate);
    update caseUpdate;

}
```

Comment: Can you try SOQL using IN clause?
SELECT CaseId,KnowledgeArticleId FROM CaseArticle WHERE caseId IN : varCaseId

Comment: @PranayJaiswal. I tried IN and using (=) both are not give me the Output. List<CaseArticle> caseArt is coming as null. But when i run the SOQL separately I am able to see the value.

Comment: What is the query you're running separately look like? I would take steps to use debug logs to check the value of varCaseId and run a subset of the code in Apex Anonymous to narrow down success/failure conditions.